# Applying function to multiple columns in pandas dataframe to make 1 new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[fruits.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbdK0.png)

> I'm trying to apply a function that:
>
> 1. takes the value of each cell in a column divided by the mean of its respective column.
> 2. Then create a column called ['Score'] that has the sum of each cell value in a row computed from step 1.

> My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('fruits.xlsx'))
def func(column):
    out = df[column].values / df[column].mean()
    return out
```

> Im really unsure of how to execute this with pandas properly.

Comment: Could you please copy+paste your data as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one will calculate exactly what you need in one single line:

```
df['Score'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum([x[i]/df[i].mean() for i in df.columns]),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df['score'] = df.div(df.mean()).sum(axis=1)
```

Output

```
    a   b   c   score
0   1   2   3   1.15
1   4   5   6   3.00
2   7   8   9   4.85
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the output as a column in the dataframe

```
df["Score"] = df[<col_name>] / df[<col_name>].mean()
```

and you can use

```
df["Score"] = df[<col_name>].values / df[<col_name>].mean()
```

I tested both and both gave me the same output in the dataframe